# MPMoviePlayerViewController not autorotating to landscape in iOS7

Tags: ios, rotation, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have an app which I want to be in portrait only mode for most of it, but when it plays videos, I want the MPMoviePlayerViewController to force itself into landscape. Then, when the video is dismissed or ended, I want the app to go back to being in portrait. I'm presenting an MPMoviePlayerViewController using the -presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated: method.

Comment: do you enable all orientation mask

Comment: If I go into the Project settings and enable the Landscape modes, I can get it to go into landscape, although the video does not start in landscape. However, doing this also requires that the rest of my app allows landscape, when it wasn't designed to do so. I would like a way to enable, if not force, landscape for the movie controller only.

Comment: I have the same problem - just wondered if you ever found a solution to it.  (There are lots of answers out there - a bit complicated for me though.) Thanks.